# I need a cron expression

Tags: ruby, cron, expression

I need a cron expression to execute some code at exactly `5:30 am` weekday.

I tried this one

```
30 5 * * 1-5
```

but it execute at 10:30 pm
Searching in internet i find this one

```
0 30 5 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

but ruby show me an exception message saying this:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:674:in `next_time_from': undefined method `next_time' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:668:in `set_next_time'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:636:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:617:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:617:in `do_schedule'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:224:in `cron'
    from E:/Marcos_Guerra/RubyWorkspace/calisoft-suite/Proyectos/RedmineApi/api.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

this is my code:

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'America/New_York'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.cron '0 30 5 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *' do
    begin
      # do something that might fail...
      # every day of the week at 05:30 am
      puts RedmineConnector.resetYourLife(user,pass)
    rescue => e

    end
  end
sleep 3
```

I'm using Rufus Gem

Comment: I think you had it right the first time, and its probably a Timezone issue rather than cron expression issue: [see crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#30_5_*_*_1-5)

Comment: thanks a lot.
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the project README](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#a-note-about-timezones), you can specify the cron job with a timezone as follows:

```
scheduler.cron '30 5 * * 1-5 America/New_York' do
  # ...
end
```

This *does* mean "at exactly 5:30am on weekdays", as you desired.